# Performing an averaging operation over every n elements in a vector

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a logical vector in which I would like to iterate over every n-elements. If in any given window at least 50% are 1's, then I change every element to 1, else I keep as is and move to the next window. For example.

```
n = 4;

input = [0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1];

output = func(input,4);

output = [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1];
```

This function is trivial to implement but is it possible to apply a vectorized implementation using logical indexing?. I am trying to build up the intuition of applying this technique.

Comment: Why is the 3rd element `0`, but the 7th a `1` in your example output? Maybe provide the trivial (non-vectorized) function for clarity.

Comment: MATLAB loops are very fast. Write a function with looping and your are good to go. There is no benefit in logical indexing over numerical indexing if you first have to create the logical vector for a one-time use. BTW, your array only becomes binary if you cast it to `logical()`

Answer (score 2):

here's a one liner (that works for your input):

```
func = @(input,n) input | kron(sum(reshape(input ,n,[]))>=n/2,ones(1,n));
```

of course, there are cases to solve that this doesnt answer, what if the size of the input is not commensurate in `n`? etc... 
i'm not sure if that's what you meant by vectorization, and I didnt benchmark it vs a for loop...

Comment: Yes although not mentioned above, but assume the length of input is an integer multiple of n

Comment: ok... if you have questions on what I did, feel free. I saw another answer by @Hoki that is pretty much the same until step 3. I really like one line solutions, so i used kron to expand the logical vector to the full form (each `1` turns to `1 1 1 1` etc). This can be also done in using bsxfun etc. How important is runtime efficiency here?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it. Once understood you can compact it in less lines but I'll details the intermediate steps for the sake of clarity.

```
%% The inputs
n = 4;
input = [0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1];
```

1) Split your input into blocks of size `n` (note that your final function will have to check that the number of elements in `input` is a integer multiple of `n`)

```
c  = reshape(input,n,[]) ;
```

Gives you a matrix with your blocks organized in columns:

```
c =
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     1     0     1     1     1
```

2) Perform your test condition on each of the block. For this we'll take advantage that Matlab is working column wise for the `sum` function:

```
>> cr = sum(c) >= (n/2)
cr =
     0     1     0     1     0
```

Now you have a logical vector `cr` containing as many elements as initial blocks. Each value is the result of the test condition over the block. The `0` blocks will be left unchanged, the `1` blocks will be forced to value `1`.

3) Force `1` columns/block to value `1`:

```
>> c(:,cr) = 1
c =
     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1
```

4) Now all is left is to unfold your matrix. You can do it several ways:

```
res = c(:) ; %% will give you a column vector
```

OR

```
>> res = reshape(c,1,[]) %% will give you a line vector
res =
     0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Thank you! I knew there was something off in my last line (not wrong but it didn't _look_ right), but I couldn't put my finger on it.